# Ternary Logic in timing diagrams

Tags: tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

I wanted to know if I can show 3 levels for signals in a timing diagram using the tikz passage.

Comment: This could help you: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/timing-diagram/

Comment: The signals should be in Voltage values. I am a novice here, can you specify where should I go about modifying the signals?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what is your subject.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.